Advice on getting Belgian health insurance after a frightening experience in the NL
I'm looking for advice on getting a private health insurance plan in Belgium. I am moving back to the Netherlands in two months to finish my studies and the prospect of having to deal with the Dutch healthcare system keeps me awake at night since five years ago I almost die due to something that could have been easily spotted and fixed with medication. It was really a frightening experience and it wasn't just one crazy doctor, sadly these things are not isolated situations in the Netherlands. My uncle lives in Belgium and I think he wouldn't mind registering me at his house. Would that be enough? Do I need to have a job in Belgium? Is it true that to have access to public health insurance you need proof of employment? What about getting private health insurance only? By the way, I have an Italian passport but I've always lived in Peru until I moved to the NL. Hopefully having an EU passport makes things easier!

Is insurance the main issue here? If I understand you correctly, what you want to avoid the most is having to seek medical help in the Netherlands (not the first time I hear this). Are you counting on Belgium insurance to make it easier to seek help in Belgium? You should be able to do that with the EHIC that comes with your Dutch insurance, presumably also without insurance. On the other hand, even if you manage to get Belgian insurance in this scenario, if you are physically in the Netherlands and you face an emergency, you will end up in a Dutch hospital all the same.

Also, are you hoping to avoid paying for Dutch health insurance and seeking advice on that? That may be possible for a student who actually resides in another EU country but may require some paperwork (not 100% up to date on that personally but if you want to know, it may be worth asking explicitly). Merely getting insurance in Belgium or planning to use the Belgian healthcare system as much as possible does not change your legal position while you reside in the Netherlands (obligation to register with the municipality and the insurance obligation stemming from that).

OK, another angle to consider: You are going to live in the Netherlands, where getting health insurance is mandatory. Why not forgo registering in Belgium and rely on your Dutch insurance? For emergencies, you can use the Dutch EHIC, even in Belgium. For GP visits, regular tests, gynaecology, the occasional specialist, etc. you could still try to get appointments in Belgium and pay out of pocket. It might still be cheaper than getting two separate insurances.

I know some people doing similar things because they prefer to get primary healthcare in their country of origin (e.g. German citizens living in the Netherlands). Main downsides is that if you need an expensive planned procedure, it will have to be in the Netherlands and I am not sure how easy it is to get appointments in Belgium if you are not insured.


Would that be enough? Do I need to have a job in Belgium? Is it true that to have access to public health insurance you need proof of employment?

Usually, this goes the other way around: To register with a Belgian municipality for a stay longer than 3 months, you need to show either that you are working (including being self-employed and looking for work) or provide proof of health insurance. That's also the way EU law on freedom of movement works in general.
A few years ago, Belgium was more aggressive than most EU countries in tracking down EU citizens who didn't meet the requirements to reside as “non-economically active” people and the website from the Immigration office suggests that it is still the case.
In practice that means that after registering, you should apparently expect a “positive residence check” (possibly someone from the municipality showing up at your door). According to the website, if you do not actually reside at the address you registered or fail to provide any of the required documents (including proof of health insurance), the municipality would escalate your case to the Immigration office. If they do not recognize your right of residence, they might issue an order to leave the territory.
So not only registering at your uncle's house is not enough to get health insurance but failing to secure insurance before you do that could even create additional issues.

What about getting private health insurance only?

Getting some sort of private insurance could be an option but that would be a different kind of insurance from the regular “private insurance” Belgian residents get, which as you noted in a comment is really supplementary insurance for people who are already affiliated with the Belgian healthcare system (mutualité / ziekenfonds).
I have no idea where to get it or how widely available it is. In any case, most insurance contracts would implicitly or explicitly require living in the country where they are issued so even if you do secure one and avoid scrutiny from the Belgian Immigration office, your insurance may turn out to be invalid when you actually need it (i.e. if you need to make a claim following some expensive procedure or hospital stay).
For completeness, note that another common scenario for EU citizens is to be covered by the healthcare system of their country of origin. That's typically possible for retirees or students coming for an exchange year. That won't be an option for you since you do not reside in Italy and a passport is not enough to get Italian health insurance. But this explains why few people are in your exact situation and it's difficult to find a good solution.

Thank you for your response! Indeed, there are many horror stories regarding the Dutch healthcare system and it's a pity because besides the rather calvinistic approach to life I've found it a really good place to live in. Although there's the possibility of ending up in a Dutch hospital due to an emergency, I am more concerned about having the option to see a decent GP, a specialist and being able to get tests or a planned intervention. I did not know that they used the term “non-economically active”, it comes in handy to know this and the link you've sent also helps a lot.

Doing more research I found out that the private Belgian health insurance works as a supplementary plan to compensate for what the public one doesn't cover in full, so getting a private health insurance only wouldn't be a good idea. I'm not looking to avoid paying my Dutch health insurance, since I do need it in case of emergencies or to get my medication (I would just keep a basic plan, though). In the NL they can verify you live at an address, but it won't happen to everyone and if the person who opens the door shows there is a bed for you, a toothbrush and some clothing that's all they need

So if I understand correctly, the Belgian government checks thoroughly for EU members residents living and working irregularities (so I should assume they will knock my uncle's door). What I don't know is if they will need to talk to me. Also, if I understand correctly, I need to provide proof of health insurance to register at a municipality,  but the health insurance will require me to be registered already? It doesn't seem so easy but I will have to see how I manage to register.

@Lucia Under EU law, there are really two very different situations: (1) you are a worker, you can register with the municipality, no questions asked, and then you can get access to the regular tax-funded mandatory health insurance or (2) you are not a worker, you need to secure some other form of insurance (including private insurance) to avoid being a “burden” to the regular health insurance system.

So the catch-22 is by design, Belgium doesn't want people from other EU country to have access to the regular health insurance if they are not workers (within the meaning of EU freedom of movement law).

Regarding house visits, I don't know how common they really are but I assume they might want to talk to you. I know the topic is somehow politically sensitive in Belgium. Most EU countries do not actively enforce the restrictions on EU freedom of movement whereas in Belgium the government used to regularly brag about it.

The type of private insurance you would need is indeed different from the supplementary insurance that's common in Belgium and other EU countries. I don't know where to get it or whether it's widely available. I will add a not to the answer. A more common scenario for EU citizens is to be covered by the health insurance system of their country of origin (works for retirees, students, posted workers…) but that's not a possibility for you since you never resided in the EU. That's one of the things where the passport isn't sufficient, residence is more important.

thank you for all the info! I had no idea that Belgium is so strict when it comes to enforcing the restrictions on EU freedom. In the Netherlands no one cares. So basically if I'm not a worker I'll have to prove I have another health insurance to be able to register at a municipality. Maybe by having a Dutch Health Insurance they'll let me? Or maybe they'll oppose to being registered in two different countries? Also I was wondering if owning a property in Belgium and renting it might make things easier. Since I'm moving permanently I've sold my house in Peru and could invest in that.

(I am so grateful for all of your comments! How do you know so much about these things?!)
